# Put callback is not called if null passed

Tags: javascript, node.js, gun

*gun 0.8.9*

I wanted to "promisify" `.put(cb)` method and noticed that the callback `cb` was never triggered if `null` passed as data.

It makes hard to control node selection. For example, if node properties were removed and I want to select only nodes which have properties. I'm not sure that `.put(null)` removed properties.

Look the code below, the callback which notifies that `dino removed` is not triggered.

```js
var gun = new Gun();
var park = gun.get('park');

var velociraptor = park.get('dino/velociraptor').put({
  statistics: {
    speed: 17,
    intelligence: 21,
    force: 11
  }
}, function (ack) {
  console.log('add dino', ack);
});

park.get('dino/velociraptor').put(null, function (ack) {
  console.log('remove dino', ack);
  alert('You have removed the velociraptor from the park!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/amark/gun/master/gun.js"></script>
```

Comment: depending on how you were planning on promisifying it, there's different workarounds. What were you going to do to promisify it?

Comment: This is likely a bug, I think you opened an issue for it on GitHub, hopefully will get around to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing about Gun, but this would be one way of handling that situatino maybe:

```
Gun.prototype.pput = function(arg){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          this.put(arg, resolve);
          if (arg === null) resolve();
    })        
}
```

Gun.pput, instead of Gun.put, would then return a promise.